# Every new loop has a different parameter value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

This is for webp using `cwebp` and I'm testing all different possible qualities, given:

```
cwebp -q 75 file.jpeg -o file.webp
```

I want a loop like:

```
for i in {1..4}; do cwebp -q ?? file.jpeg -o file.webp; done
```

Where ?? should change for specific values, like:

- 75 for the first loop
- 80 for the second loop
- 85 for the third loop
- 90 for the fourth loop

How do I automatize that so I don't need to type 4 times the same command and change the parameters which time

- I want a bash command in one line or a script, not any other programming language.
- I'm not sure if the right command is `for`, `while` or another

Comment: Something like `for i in 75 80 85 90; do cwebp -q $i file.jpeg -o file.webp; done`?

Comment: `for i in 75 80 85 90; do cwebp -q "$i" file.jpeg -o file.webp; done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you want is something like:

```
for i in 75 80 85 90; do cwebp -q "$i" file.jpeg -o file.webp; done
```

Though this will overwrite the output file each time, so you might want to use the quality in the output filename:

```
for i in 75 80 85 90; do cwebp -q "$i" file.jpeg -o file-"$i".webp; done
```

If the values 75, ..., 90 are not arbitrary, and you know you will start at X and end at Y in steps of Z, you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) or [an arithmetic `for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) to generate those values:

```
for i in {75..90..5}; do cwebp -q "$i" file.jpeg -o file-"$i".webp; done
for ((i = 75; i <= 90; i += 5)); do cwebp -q "$i" file.jpeg -o file-"$i".webp; done
```

Comment: Great answer! I believe it's the closest to what I want. Just for curiosity. If I go further and ask. Is it possible to have a completely new command for which loop or that would be too impossible? I'll make a new question if necessary.

Comment: @SatoshiNakamoto I don't really understand what you mean by that. Do you mean you to do something like run `foo` for 1, `bar baz` for 2, etc.? That will be tricky, since you'll need to store the association between the index and the command somewhere, and running commands stored in a variable is tricky. If they're completely different commands, would a loop even make sense? It'd just be a plain sequence of commands, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try also to use `seq`

```
for i in $(seq 75 90 5); do cwebp -q "$i" file.jpeg -o file-"$i".webp; done
```